# Joining a QUERY function with OR

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-query-language, nested-if

I currently have a QUERY function which is set up based on a start date cell and an end date cell, formula as below:

`=QUERY(Haulage!$A$3:$L$29," Select * Where A >= date """&text('2022 Stats'!S1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&""" AND A <= date  """&text('2022 Stats'!T1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"""")`

This is working fine but I would like to adapt it so I can also narrow the query down further with the use of a dropdown. I have the following IF formula for this:

`=IF('2022 Stats'!V1="All TOCs",""," AND LOWER(K) = LOWER('"&'2022 Stats'!V1&"') " )`

This seems to yield the correct results but I am struggling to get the two to work together......

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wTWuvFwMTqJ-sjIZbXWpGOS1WKwpODj2R8KAzqlqkuw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=QUERY(Haulage!A3:L29,
 "where A >= date '"&TEXT('2022 Stats'!S1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date '"&TEXT('2022 Stats'!T1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"&
 IF('2022 Stats'!V1="All TOCs",,"
    and lower(K) = '"&LOWER('2022 Stats'!V1)&"'"))
```

Comment: That's the one @player0 - I know this is a slightly different question but with my QUERY, I am loading it into row 2 but it is shunting my results down to row 3 onwards which is creating an additional 'blank' record which is appearing in my Stats sheet

How can I stop the QUERY from dropping down in this manner?

Comment: @The_Train change the ending `))` to `),)`

Comment: Perfect @player0 - I'm now seeking to add another dropdown option which I thought would be a simple process but I've hit a brick wall as this one consists of numbers. I will continue to try and figure it myself but may be back later for some further assistance

Comment: Not sure if I am heading along the right track @player0 but I reached this point......=QUERY(Haulage!$A$3:$L$29," Select * Where A >= date '"&TEXT('2022 Stats'!S1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
and A <= date  '"&TEXT('2022 Stats'!T1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"&
IF('2022 Stats'!V1="All TOCs",," AND lower(K) = '"&LOWER('2022 Stats'!V1)&"'"&
IF('2022 Stats'!W1="All Classes",," AND (L) = "&('2022 Stats'!W1)&"")),)

I've also tried to add TO_TEXT as it seems to be not liking the fact that this 2nd dropdown is numerical but to no avail......

Comment: @The_Train hard to tell like this but try: `=QUERY(Haulage!A3:L29,
 "where A >= date '"&TEXT('2022 Stats'!S1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date '"&TEXT('2022 Stats'!T1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"& 
 IF('2022 Stats'!V1="All TOCs",," 
    and lower(K) = '"&LOWER('2022 Stats'!V1)&"'")& 
 IF('2022 Stats'!W1="All Classes",," 
    and L = "&'2022 Stats'!W1*1), )`